# Select2 open another select2 on 1st select2 open event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

```js
$(".js-example-events").select2();

$('.js-example-events').on("select2:open", function () {
    $("#s1").select2("open");
});

function test(){
    $("#s1").select2("open");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
                                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css"/>

<select class="js-example-events" style="width:300px;">
<option>Select One</option>
<option>Select1</option>
</select>

<select class="js-example-events" id="s1" style="width:300px;">
<option>Selects Two</option>
<option>Select1</option>
</select>

<button onclick="test()">
Test
</button>
```

I want to open 2 select2 at a time.

It works when I use a button click event, but not when I use select2 open event

```
<select class="js-example-events" style="width:300px;">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option>Select1</option>
</select>

<select class="js-example-events" id="s1" style="width:300px;">
    <option>Selects Two</option>
    <option>Select1</option>
</select>

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

JS

```
$(".js-example-events").select2();

$('.js-example-events').on("select2:open", function () {
    $("#s1").select2("open");  // not working here
});

function test(){
    $("#s1").select2("open"); // but work here well
}
```

Working JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gqo5cL6x/

**select2("open");** is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two case:

Case 1: Not run before select2 because you run before select2, it changes on HTML. Therefore you call function not run. You use code below:

```
$(".js-example-events").on("click", function () { 
   $("#s1").select2();
   $("#s1").select2("open");
   $(this).select2();
   $(this).select2("open");
});
```

Case 2: Keep your code you need call event to code below:

```
$(".js-example-events").select2();

$("span[class='select2-selection select2-selection-- 
 single']").on("click", 
function () { 
   $("#s1").select2("open");
  $(this).select2("open");
});
```

Comment: test() is working for me as well. I want to add **open** in **$('.js-example-events').on("select2:open", function () {**

Comment: test() is not the issue

Comment: $('select[class='js-example-events']').on("select2:open", function () {
    $("#s1").select2("open");  // not working here
}); you try.

Comment: Still not working. can you share working jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/nc9k2jsd/

Comment: I did change. I did run on  jsfiddle.net/nc9k2jsd rahul.m